# Refresh Browser on Window Resize (only when it is being expanded or made larger)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I found a couple different answers already such as this one [How can I refresh the screen on browser resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836779/how-can-i-refresh-the-screen-on-browser-resize) however I don't want it to just refresh any time the window resizes, only when the window is made larger.

This is a dirty workaround for a bootstrap menu bug. Every time i resize the window smaller the menu stays where it needs to, however when i resize the window back to larger size from small, the menus drops down below itself. It only does this in chrome and firefox. However its a annoying enough bug that I implemented the refresh triggered by resize JS but it was getting annoying with it refreshing anytime the window was resized in any way.

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer seems appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12661128/498768

In summary: **Keep track of window size using variables**. (see the linked answer for a code example)